# Grabbing JSON data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm working on jQuery for the first time. When I use this:

```
      var data = $.getJSON("https://hackernews.firebaseio.com/v0/item/14279870.json", function(data) {
        data = JSON.stringify(data)
      });
      console.log(data);
```

I get this guy in the log: [object view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MunsT.png)[image]

But if I try to log data.text, data.responseText, or anything like that I just get undefined. How do I get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `console.log` executes before `data = JSON.stringify(data)` because `$.getJSON` call is asynchronous.

That means that what you see in the console is not the object that you get inside your success callback.

To get a proper representation of your data object (after the server call), put the console log inside the callback function:

```
$.getJSON("https://hackernews.firebaseio.com/v0/item/14279870.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.stringify(data)
    console.log(data);
  });
```

---

Live example with a sample JSON file (your URL returns null):

```js
$.getJSON("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two", function(data) {
        console.log("JSON: ", data);
        data = JSON.stringify(data)
        console.log("Stringified: ", data);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!